# PHP Simple Html Dom Parser - "double" dimension arrays

Tags: php, domparser

I realize there are no multi-dimension arrays with PHP, however here is the issue.

I have this inside a for ($fix) loop:

```
$html->find('tr[class] td', $fix);
```

Now in a row there are more than one td being grabbed, so say the first one holds the username

I would like to grab the username, and this is what I'm trying but its not working:

```
$username = $html[0];
```

I also tried something like this

```
$username = $html->find('tr[class] td', $fix, 0)
```

Neither of these works, what should I be using?

Full Code:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $q=$_REQUEST["q"]; $hint="";
    $ctx = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'timeout' => 15
            )
        )
    ); 
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/index.php?q=' . urlencode($q), 0, $ctx);
    $tr = $html->find('tr');
    // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
    $fix = 0;

    if ($q !== "") { 
        $q=strtolower($q); $len=strlen($q);
        foreach($tr as $name) {  
            $fix++;
            if($fix > 2) {
                $selector = $html->find('tr[class] td');
                $username = $selector[$fix][0]->plaintext;
                $name = $selector;
                $username_fix = str_replace ('.',"",$username);
                if ($hint==="") { 
                    $hint='<tr>
                                <td>' . $name->plaintext . '<br />' . $username . '</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#M' . $username_fix . '">This is me!</button></td>
                                <div class="modal fade" id="M' . $username_fix . '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Yo</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <p>Hey&hellip;' . $name->plaintext . '</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </tr>'; 
                } else { 
                    $hint .='<tr>
                                  <td>' . $name->plaintext . '<br />' . $username . '</td>
                                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#M' . $username_fix . '">This is me!</button></td>
                                  <div class="modal fade" id="M' . $username_fix . '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Yo</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <p>Hey&hellip;' . $name->plaintext . '</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </tr>'; 
                }
            }
        }
      }
    // Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
    // or output the correct values
    if($hint === "") {
        echo 'My records indicate you a liar!';
    } else {
        echo '
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th style="min-width:20%;">Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th width="9%">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        ';
        echo $hint;
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>
```

still dirty as ever, would like it functional first

Comment: `I realize there are no multi-dimension arrays with PHP`. Oh, really?

Comment: could you post your complete code